# Reading contents of .txt file and showing it in multiple text areas

Tags: java, swing, file-io, java-io

I am trying to read content from a .txt file and I want to show it in number of JTextAreas in my GUI

Contents of my text file is 8 random numbers with comma separating them from each other (like following)

200,140,300,30,30,70,70,20

I have 8 JTextArea on my GUI and I want to show each number in different JTextArea.

So how can I use comma (,) in a text file as a delimiter?

Following code is opening file perfectly but it is showing content of selected .txt file in only one text area. How can i edit my code to achieve the goal?

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                  try 
                  {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                    o = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    while((s=o.readLine())!=null)
                        t1.setText(s);
                  } 
                  catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  } 
                  catch (IOException e) 
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }                 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do not forget to call `fr.close()` in a `finally`-block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to tokenize the contents of the text file specifying the ", " as a separator.

```
String content = "200, 140, 300, 30, 30, 70, 70, 20;
String[] tokens = content.split(", ");
```

After that you can access each number in the tokens array.

Answer (score 2):

You can split this numbers by using **s.split(",")**

Try this

```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader o = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        while ((s = o.readLine()) != null) {
            String Values[] = s.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Values[i]);//////////here You can set JTextArea by using Values[i]

            }
        }
```